# Created array inside a for loop cannot be accessed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array:

```
for (i = 0; i < this.platforms_values.length; i++){

    platform_project: [
         {owner_id: owner_id},
         {project_id: project_id},
    ]

    platform_project.push(this.platforms_values[i])
}
```

However it gives me this:

```
platform_project is not defined
```

Comment: platform_project platform_project is not defined - you have not declare it yet you have to declare first then initilize it will []

Comment: Note that even if `platform_project: []` were the correct syntax for declaring an array, you'd still be redeclaring it in every iteration, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Read a javascript tutorial. You are using a label'ed statement, which is absolutely not what you want to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're doing 2 things wrong.

1) creating a new object at every instance of the loop

2) using a colon instead of an equals for assignment

```
const platform_project = [
     {owner_id: owner_id},
     {project_id: project_id},
];
for (let i = 0; i < this.platforms_values.length; i++) {        
    platform_project.push(this.platforms_values[i])
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not the correct way to declare variable. You need to use either `var`, `let` or `const`, and an `=` sign.

Also, your variable is redeclare each time you loop, so it become useless. You should declare it before the loop.

```
const platform_project = [
         {owner_id: owner_id},
         {project_id: project_id},
]


for (i = 0; i < this.platforms_values.length; i++){
    platform_project.push(this.platforms_values[i])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.platforms_values.length; i++){

    var platform_project = [
         {owner_id: owner_id},
         {project_id: project_id},
    ]

    platform_project.push(this.platforms_values[i])
}
```

You're using the syntax for assigning a value to an object property. The above syntax is correct for assigning a value to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Assignment in JavaScript is done via `=`, not `:`. You only use `:` within an object literal. So:

```
platform_project = [
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
     {owner_id: owner_id},
     {project_id: project_id},
]
```

You also need to declare your variables (`i`, `platform_project`) if you haven't already.

But see [Keenan Diggs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036850/157247), it's not clear you really want to create that array *inside* the loop...

---

You might be wondering why you didn't get a syntax error from the `:` version. The reason is that the code parsed just fine, because `platform_project` was seen as a *label* for the following statement (you know labels, those things you can use on nested loops to direct a `break` or `continue` to the outer loop), and an array literal is a valid statement (because in JavaScript, all expressions are valid statements).